# "Более(,) чем неравный

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в обороте "Более(,) чем неравный"? Заранее благодарю, а то я уже запуталась, где запятая нужна, а где нет))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не нужна. 
***Более чем неравный.*** Здесь слово "более" употребляется не в сравнении, а как единое целое со второй частью словосочетания.

вот цитата из офиц. источника 
"Однако при отсутствии сравниваемых понятий слова «(не) более / больше чем» образуют с последующими словами неразложимое сочетание (единый член предложения), не требующее постановки знаков препинания".